# What is difference between action, category, activity name in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

there are android:name 3 times, What is difference  between them? I started learn Android, so now I am trying to understand Manifest.

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.example.project.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html. check this

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html   And this

Answer (score 0):

An activity is the user interface you provide to your user. An intent filter is like a "port" you add your activity to and allow other applications to search for all applications running on the "port" and call them. The action name is just what the app is meant to do when called.

Answer (score 0):

`android` is the package, `name` is the field. In XML you write the full access like this: `android.name`.